# Disappearing background image in IE 7 only

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Have a problem with my submit button image disappearing but only in IE7 and below. I've tried:

- adding a border color
- adding `background-color`
- adding `min-height: 22px` to trigger `hasLayout`
- adding `display: inline-block;`

but NONE worked.

This is my form: http://www.bitstream.ca/contact.html

**HTML:**

```
<button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

**CSS :**

```
#submit{
    background: url('imgs/submit.png') no-repeat top;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 79px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding a `width` and `height` to an inline element. Inline elements are unable to have a `width` or `height` set on them, so if you set the element to `display: block;` and it should solve your problems.

Comment: just edited my question, adding display: inline-block; doesn't work either:(